# Does MATLAB have any kind of debug mode that shows vector and matrix dimensions?

Tags: matlab, debugging, matrix

I'm new to MATLAB (using it for a course on machine learning).

There are parts of the language that are just fabulous - for example, the notational convenience of vector and matrix math. But I find I'm struggling with cause-and-effect of various operations (for example, ".*" vs. "*"), and what I end up doing is decomposing lines of code into constituent expressions to see what dimensions they produce.

Is there any "mode" (for lack of a better word) in MATLAB that would show me what the dimensions of the intermediate expressions are?

The closest equivalent I can think of is the SQL Server Query Analyzer, which decomposes the SQL query (also set-oriented) into a series of steps that give you a clue as to what's being executed as opposed to what you intended.

Does such a thing exist in MATLAB or any of its extensions?

TIA
Josh

Comment: Yes. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/examine-values.html

Comment: Datatips look very useful. I'm not sure if they work on a highlighted expression, but it won't take long to find out.

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

There's the undocumented option `format debug`, which lets you do this sort of thing:

```
>> format debug
>> x = rand(3)
x =

Structure address = 7fed6d1cada0
m = 3
n = 3
pr = 7fecdd3353e0
pi = 0
    0.9649    0.9572    0.1419
    0.1576    0.4854    0.4218
    0.9706    0.8003    0.9157
```

This only really works well for 2-D arrays though.

Comment: Hmmm ... it's not perfect, but closer to what I'm looking for. I'll give this a spin.

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

As beaker pointed out, you can use [MATLAB's debug mode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) by setting breakpoints along its mlint "editor" (the column on the left side of the editor with each line number).

Also, for your question about the dimensions.  Use the [`size()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function with the intermediate variable or expression interest to determine its dimensions.

Once your program has stopped at the breakpoint you set, you would use the command window to execute your the function call like this:
`size(X)` 
or perhaps `size(X*A)` depending on what your variables of interest are.  Note, don't include a `;` at the end of these calls, or the output will not be displayed.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to use breakpoints and the command window (and what ; does), but I'm finding those arduous for doing just basic things. I'd rather have something like a "what-if" mode -- if it exists.

Comment: Sure thing.  Sorry, I couldn't be of more help.  I tend to think of MATLAB as one big "what if" environment, stepping into function calls to see what is happening and evaluating intermediate expressions on the console as I go along.  You are right though, it can get tedious.  I'll keep an eye out on the other responses that come in.  Hopefully you'll find something more suitable.